# How to pivot on 2 fields

Tags: sql, pivot

Here is the table I have:

```
PeriodID  RecordID  Basis   Amount1 Amount2
1        1          IFRS    10  100
1        2          IFRS    20  200
2        1          IFRS    15  150
2        2          IFRS    25  250
1        1          CGAAP   30  300
1        2          CGAAP   40  400
2        1          CGAAP   35  350
2        2          CGAAP   45  450
```

I would like to pivot on the PeriodID and Basis field so that the result would have following columns:

```
RecordID 
Period1IFRSAmount1  
Period2IFRSAmount1  
PeriodID1IFRSAmount2    
PeriodID2IFRSAmount2    
Period1CGAAPAmount1 
Period2CGAAPAmount1 
PeriodID1CGAAPAmount2   
PeriodID2IFRSAmount22
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please include the exact expected output from your sample input data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create the ouput that you need as rows. That is why union part is really important. After you construct your data you can easily use PIVOT.

Following query written in SQL SERVER. It should be similar to other databases as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT RecordID, 'Period' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, PeriodID) + Basis + 'Amount1' AS Basis, Amount1 AS Amount
    FROM TableName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT RecordID, 'Period' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, PeriodID) + Basis + 'Amount2' AS Basis, Amount2 AS AMOUNT
    FROM TableName
) AS Q
PIVOT (
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR Basis IN
    (
        [Period1IFRSAmount1],
        [Period2IFRSAmount1],
        [Period1IFRSAmount2],
        [Period2IFRSAmount2],
        [Period1CGAAPAmount1],
        [Period2CGAAPAmount1],
        [Period1CGAAPAmount2],
        [Period2CGAAPAmount2]
    )
) AS P
```